# Why are CSS bounds only calculated correctly on page load?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve the problem that I want to have a square element that gets its edge size from the page height. In other words, I want to bind the width of the element to its height.

I know this can be achieved the [other way round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width), and I could also use [`vh`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), but I am doing this as an exercise.

My approach was to exploit the fact that `img` tags can maintain the aspect-ratio of the displayed image. I have come up with the following html (the `img` tag embeds a 1x1px gif):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="circle-tree">
            <div class="circle-tree-wrap">
                <!-- Play with img tag to get an element that adjusts its width to its height -->
                <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIAAAP///////ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=">
                <div class="circle-tree-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Along with it, I wrote this CSS:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

body {
  background-color: #64d0ac; }

.circle-tree {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50%); }
  .circle-tree .circle-tree-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%; }
    .circle-tree .circle-tree-wrap .circle-tree-content {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateX(-50%); }
    .circle-tree .circle-tree-wrap img {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(-50%); }
```

This works when I initially load the page (`.circle-tree-content` is square and has 100% height). But when I resize the browser window, `.circle-tree-wrap` will not adjust its width to the new width of the `img` element. Another reload fixes it again. I tested this both in Chromium 43 and Firefox 38. I know you probably wouldn't want to do this in production and I will probably go with one of the other solutions eventually (or JS).

But since I find this behavior utterly peculiar, I wanted to ask here on SO if anyone can explain to me why CSS is being calculated differently when it comes to resize vs. page load. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Good question. The code to demonstrate the issue can be made much simpler though, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bppxfw0u/). Reside the height of the output pane and the green block won't change width. Press "Run" and it's a square again. Behaviour is the same across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to how browsers calculate the "[shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#shrink-to-fit)" or "preferred" width for inline elements when no specific width value is declared. I assume that the width of the container div around the image is not being recalculated properly when the browser gets resized because the image element does not create a **line break** similar to text. See the code example below or this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bppxfw0u/4/) and shrink the window width down. You will see that the width of the `.circle-tree-wrap` div elements shrink to fit the text when it breaks the line but not the image.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-color:black;
}
.circle-tree-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    background-color:grey;
}
img {
    vertical-align:top;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    opacity:0.7;
}
em {
    vertical-align:top;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-tree-wrap">
    <!-- Play with img tag to get an element that adjusts its width to its height -->
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIAAAP///////ywAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs="/>
</div>
<div class="circle-tree-wrap"><em>some text to fill the space</em>
<div>
```